# Ajuda com SELECT pra exame de facudade

Tags: sql, select

preciso de ajuda com um teste de faculdade. Sou novo em `SQL`, e preciso ir bem nesse teste. Será que alguém podia me ajudar a formar esse `SELECT` de maneira correta?

Nem sei direito por onde começar, agradeço muito qualquer ajuda. Sei que devo estudar pra atingir as respostas sozinho, mas a entrega é até hoje a noite dia 21/02.

---

Somos a empresa *X* e nossa venda é focada em bolsas e sapatos diversificados.

Queremos fazer uma campanha para oferecer uma Scarpin para todos aqueles que compraram na *categoria "Sandália"* há exatos 30 dias atrás com *ticket médio de R$150,00* em sua última compra.

Faça uma consulta no banco de dados usando linguagem `SQL` Query que atenda os critérios estabelecidos. Considere o campo “email” como chave primária.

```
Tabela 1  
tb_orders

Campos:

id_pedido
Email
Nome
Valor total
Quantidade de itens
data_compra
```

*⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀*

```
Tabela 2  
tb_itens_orders

Campos:

id_pedido
nome_produto
sku_produto
categoria
preco
```

Comment: Me perdoe, mas falta um pouco na sua pergunta para o site... Se possível leia isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e seria ótimo se pudesse aplicar ;)

Comment: "há exatos 30 dias atrás", é isso mesmo? Quem comprou a 29 ou 31 dias não entra? O que vem a ser "ticket médio de R$150,00 em sua última compra", média do que?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que vai ficar mais ou menos assim, porém não consigo testar.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_orders as tor, tb_itens_orders as ti 
WHERE tor.id_pedido = ti.idpedido 
AND
tor.data_compra BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
AND
ti.nome_produto = 'Sandalia'
```

Comment: Obrigado meu camarada, de coração.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   o.email, 
         AVG(o.valor_total / o.quantidade_de_itens) ticket_medio
FROM     tbl_orders o
JOIN     tbl_itens_orders i ON i.id_pedido = o.id_pedido
WHERE    i.categoria = 'Sandália' 
AND      o.data_compra = '2019-01-22' --considerando hoje como 21/fev/2019
GROUP BY o.email
HAVING   ticket_medio >= 150.00
```